# how would I include some html in the header section of a wordpress plugin? I get an error

Tags: plugins, headers

When I include some div into a plugin I am creating I get an error when activating the plugin.
*"The plugin generated 33 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin."*

Though the plugin works on the site but I get an error when activating it.
here is the plugin code. I want it to display the text on top of the page. I understand I need to use some hooks, but which one? hre is a link showing what I want.
http://wsoplugins.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Captur.png

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: test
Plugin URI:
Description: test
Author: Ronny Kibet
Author URI: 
version: 1.0
*/

?>
<div id="bar">hello there</div>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you want to output this html? Or, what does your plugin exactly do?

Comment: I want the plugin to display the text on top of the page.

Comment: Top of the page? Where exactly? Can you make an image and point where you want the text to appear on your page?

Comment: here is a link showing what I want.http://wsoplugins.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Captur.png

Comment: Check my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer...

```
add_action('init', 'text_on_top');

function text_on_top(){
    ?>
        <div id="bar">hello there</div>
    <?
}
```

Never output anything outside of a function, use a suitable action/filter to do so!